# How to store matrix into 2D array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, matrix, fortran, runtime-error, eof

okay i have a file that looks like this:

```
2 3
6 6 22
-1 3 0
```

the integers in the first row are the dimensions of the matrix (not to be included in the matrix)
the rows below the dimensions are the actual matrix
i am trying to write a program that stores this matrix into a 2D array but i keep getting a runtime error when i try to read in the matrix with the nested do loop. It keeps saying "fortran runtime error: end of file" here is my code

```
PROGRAM addsub
IMPLICIT NONE

CHARACTER(30)::file1
INTEGER:: i,j,err1
INTEGER, DIMENSION(1)::dim1r,dim1c
REAL, ALLOCATABLE:: array1(:,:)


WRITE(*,101) "What is the first filename?"
READ(*,*) file1

OPEN (UNIT=11, FILE=file1, STATUS="OLD", ACTION="READ", IOSTAT=err1)
IF (err1 .NE. 0) THEN
    WRITE(*,'(2A)')"There was an error opening ", file1
    STOP
END IF

DO i=1,1,1
    READ(11,*)dim1r(1),dim1c(1)
END DO

ALLOCATE(array1(dim1r(1),dim1c(1)))

REWIND(11)
DO i=1,dim1r(1),1
    DO j=1,dim1c(1),1
        READ(11,*) array1(i,j)
    END DO
END DO

END PROGRAM addsub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that each of your `READ` statements are trying to read a separate line; so you're trying to read 6 lines, and your file doesn't have that many.

There's a few ways around this:

You can try to read each number one at a time using `advance='no'`, but that means you can't use list-directed input and need to use formatting explicitly:

```
DO i=1,dim1r
    DO j=1,dim1c-1
        READ(11,FMT='(F2.0)',advance='no') array1(i,j)
        PRINT *, array1(i,j)
    END DO
    READ(11,FMT='(F2.0)') array1(i,dim1c)
END DO
```

You can use implied do loops to read an entire row at once:

```
DO i=1,dim1r
    READ(11,*) (array1(i,j),j=1,dim1c)
END DO
```

Or just have read deal with it by giving it the array slice:

```
DO i=1,dim1r
    READ(11,*) array1(i,1:dim1c)
END DO
```

Note another couple of things -- `dim1c` and `dim1r` don't have to be arrays; and you shouldn't `REWIND` after reading the header, or else you'll read the header in as data.

So a complete working version looks like this:

```
PROGRAM addsub
IMPLICIT NONE

CHARACTER(30)::file1
INTEGER:: i,err1
INTEGER ::dim1r,dim1c
REAL, ALLOCATABLE:: array1(:,:)


PRINT *, "What is the first filename?"
READ(*,*) file1

OPEN (UNIT=11, FILE=file1, STATUS="OLD", ACTION="READ", IOSTAT=err1)
IF (err1 .NE. 0) THEN
    WRITE(*,'(2A)')"There was an error opening ", file1
    STOP
END IF

DO i=1,1,1
    READ(11,*)dim1r, dim1c
END DO

ALLOCATE(array1(dim1r,dim1c))

DO i=1,dim1r
    READ(11,*) array1(i,1:dim1c)
END DO

DO i=1,dim1r
    PRINT *, array1(i,:)
END DO

DEALLOCATE(array1)

END PROGRAM addsub
```

Comment: ahh i see. THANK YOU so much. your solution definitely helped me.